# Find all data using foreign key from referenced table in spring boot jpa

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have done the jpa one to many mapping between Book & corresponding Pages as follows.

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
public class Book {
    @Id
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    @Column(name = "book_id")
    private String bookId;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Page.class, cascade= CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "book_id_fk", referencedColumnName = "book_id")
    private List<Page> pages;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Page {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer sno;

    private Integer number;
}

@Repository
public interface PageRepository extends JpaRepository<Page, Integer> {
    List<Page> findAllByBook_Id(String bookId);
}
```

Now I would like to get all pages using book id from Page table. For that I'm using findAllBook_id method but I'm getting the `No property book found for type Page!` exception. I tried XXXBook_fkId/XXXBookFkId/XXXBook_fk_id etc. method names but didn't worked out. Kindly help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that you face is that your `entity` `Page` does not have a field that relates with `Book`. So you have **unidirectional mapping** in JPA layer.

One solution would be to include the following custom query which will return you what you expect to be returned.

```
 @Query( "SELECT pg FROM Book bk join bk.pages pg WHERE bk.bookId = :bookId")
 List<Page> findPagesByBookId(@Param("bookId") String bookId);
```

Comment: Thank you. It's working but is there a way for us to achieve the same using without query annotation? I mean can we leverage the custom methods( which internally generates this query) ? Kindly provide your inputs

Comment: @Rajeev you should then implement a bidirectional relationship on `Page` entity and use this as a field in the jpa method name